# C#, ANTLR4 and namespaces

Tags: c#, namespaces, antlr, antlr4

I recently started to play with ANTLR4 and C#. I like the whole support that extensions give to Visual Studio. What I do not like is that whenever I generate Lexer/Parser, it is being through into the default namespace of my project - which is not what I want and as it generates automatically, it's kind of hopeless activity to try to push it into the proper namespace manually. Is there any way to change that? @parser/lexer::namespace {  } and namespace in options (with or without specified language) do not seem to work.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the **Custom Tool Namespace** property for the grammar file in the project, as described in the [Readme](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/blob/master/Readme.md) file.

Comment: Not an option, if you add the grammar to an existing project and do not put the parser in an own project ...

Comment: @Markus I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @SamHarwell Forget it, was my mistake sorry! I didn't know, there is a setting in the FileProperties ... learned something new here, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

`java -jar antlr4.jar -package NameSpace -Dlanguage=CSharp grammar.g4`

Insert your namespace in **NameSpace** above, and it will create your codes within that namespace.

Answer (score -1):

We were also attempting to use: @parser/lexer::namespace { } and found that it didn't work. We worked around the problem using the -package option to the code generator.

It's obviously not a high priority, but we are wondering if a fix for this might be coming?